# I can't handle a z-index with position absolute

Tags: css

Hhere's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-williamson-l52pr) that running the code, you'll figure out that `more` button (3 dots) is displayed over the `more-menu`. Click on the 3 dots to see what i mean.

Here's the css code of `more-menu`:

```css
.more-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 900;
  float: left;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 29px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 45px);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccd8e0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 15px) scale(0.95);
  transform: translate(0, 15px) scale(0.95);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.more-dot {
  background-color: #d7262c;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-more-menu">
  <button id="more-btn">
    <span class="more-dot" />
    <span class="more-dot" />
    <span class="more-dot" />
  </button>
  <div class="more-menu" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="more-menu-caret">
      <div class="more-menu-caret-outer" />
      <div class="more-menu-caret-inner" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really post the bare minimum in your question in order for people to help instead of forcing them to hunt down your code and filter through multiple files. [mcve]

Comment: ok, I'll edit the post.

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: @karthick I expect that `more-menu` is displayed of the menu (3 dots)

Comment: I see what you want but your fiddle doesnt work and the codesandbox is cut off on the left side of the screen making it harder to see what you are requesting

Comment: The snippet doesn't work because `opacity` is set to 0 so you can't see the menu. And it is absolutely positioned at 100% top, so at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @imvain2 try to click on the 3 dots, you'll see part of menu behind the below 3 dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `transform` property on your `container` elements is giving them their own [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) which is inherited by the `more` containers. And since your buttons and menus are sibling elements, the z-index property has no bearing on their positions relative to one another.  A simple fix would be to just remove the `transform` from your `.container` elements and find another way to position them the way you want.  I would give a suggestion but I'm not quite sure of the effect you're going for.

I made a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/pfboz) where I just removed the `transform` and `top: 100%` from the menu, it's centered but stacks as you wanted.